# Error: The tuning parameter grid should have columns parameter

Tags: r, r-caret

I try to run a 10 fold lasso regression by using R, but when I run the `tuneGrid`, it shows this error and I don't know how to fix it. Here is my code:

```
ctrlspecs<-trainControl(method="cv",number=10, savePredictions="all", classProb=TRUE)
lambdas<-c(seq(0,2,length=3))

foldlasso<-train(y1~x1,data=train_dat, method="glm", mtryGrid=expand.grid(alpha=1,lambda=lambdas),
                 trControl=ctrlspecs,tuneGrid=expand.grid(.alpha=1,.lambda=lambdas),na.action=na.omit)
```

Answer (score 0):

Clean your code!!!

```
ctrlspecs <-
  trainControl(
    method = "cv",
    number = 10,
    savePredictions = "all",
    classProb = TRUE
  )

lambdas <- c(seq(0, 2, length = 3))

foldlasso <-
  train(
    y1~x1,
    data=train_dat,        
    method = "glm",
    mtryGrid = expand.grid(alpha = 1, lambda = lambdas),
    trControl = ctrlspecs,
    na.action = na.omit
  )
```